# Filter services based on Eureka metadata with Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

We use Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul along with Eureka in our environment.

I understand Ribbon obtains the server list from Eureka for specified serviceId. In our case we have 4 containers of a service, one of the container is the master which performs resource intense tasks.
I would like to filter out master container from list of servers so Ribbon doesnt forward any requests to the container.

How do I filter ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: nothing out of the box. You'd need to write something custom

Answer (score 2):

I was able to filter by creating a new custom IRule

```
 homeautomation.ribbon.NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName=com.example.CustomZoneAvoidanceRule
```

and extending the default ZoneAvoidanceRule

```
public class CustomZoneAvoidanceRule extends ZoneAvoidanceRule {

@Override
public Server choose(final Object key) {
    final Server server = super.choose(key);
    // code to skip specific instance based on eureka metadata.
    return server;
}
```

}